# Group multiple barcodes on a single sticker together from an image with multiple stickers using python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, barcode, zbar

Objective: Automate the scanning of our product's barcodes into our shipping program using the Python language.

Situation: Each sticker on a product has two barcodes. One (the SKU) identifies what the product line is, and the other (serial number) is a unique ID identifying it from the others in the same product line. For example, in an image, there could be ten stickers with the same SKU of, say, "Product A" and all ten of those stickers have unique serial numbers. There could also be "Product B" and "Product C" in the image as well.

Progress: I can use pyzbar and cv2 to scan multiple barcodes in an image successfully.

Issue: I want to group the SKU and Serial number barcodes by sticker, but I don't know how to do this or where to start.

Code I am using

```py
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, ZBarSymbol
import cv2

testing_image_readin = cv2.imread(testing_image_path)
detected_barcodes = decode(testing_image_readin, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.CODE128, ZBarSymbol.EAN13])

if not detected_barcodes:
    print("Barcode Not Detected or your barcode is blank/corrupted!")
else:
    for barcode in detected_barcodes:
        # Locate the barcode position in image
        (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect

        cv2.rectangle(testing_image_readin, (x - 10, y - 10),
                      (x + w + 10, y + h + 10),
                      (255, 0, 0), 2)

        if barcode.data != "":
            # Print the barcode data
            print(barcode.data)
            print(barcode.type)
```

UPDATE - Adding Example Images:

I dont have an example of the exact image I am describing so I have made one in with graphics. This would be a top-down image looking at the stickers on the Product Boxes.

Example Box:

[image: Example Box]

Program output:

```
b'07FFD58D47189877'
CODE128
b'0871828002084'
EAN13
```

[image: program output]

Generated Top Down view of multiple boxes together All with unique serial numbers:

[image: Generated Top Down view of multiple boxes together All with unique serial numbers.]

Comment: [mre] implies input data. please provide some. no screenshots.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz My apologies, I didn't realize. I don't have permission to embed images, but I have added links to several images. One is an example of what a product would like with two barcodes on a single sticker that I would like to group. The other I made in a graphics program to show a bunch together look top down at them.

Comment: ok so you have a picture (at a time) and it contains exactly two codes, and they belong together? good, there's no way to mix anything up so far. just find and decode them, and you're done? I'm not sure I'm seeing the problem

Comment: ah, do you _do_ intend to work with pictures that contain **multiple boxes**, so that's why you need to group those codes... okay, thinking... so this is now an association problem. pick any barcode, and its bounding box. enlarge the box by some factor (relative to its own size). see if any other barcodes intersect with that enlarged box. associate those (and remove from "singles pool"). repeat. done. I'll do a write-up.

Comment: I'm gonna have to fix up that "multiple boxes" picture since it's not decodable.

Comment: weird. seems like pyzbar has trouble generating sensible bounding boxes if multiple codes of the same type are in the picture, and they're roughly aligned to each other. try it on this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueVLr.png

Comment: wow. pyzbar/zbar fails entirely if the codes are rotated too much. I am incredibly disappointed by that thing. I'll see if opencv's barcode detection/decoding can help here.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I'm open to using a different library if pyzbar is not ideal. I'm not married to it, it just seemed to be a popular pick when I was googling and so far has worked well for me. I'm open to a different approach as well, like I said, I don't even know where to start with this problem. Also, FYI, I am currently in an Asian timezone for a couple of weeks so my replies may be delayed.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz oh and thanks for embedding those images for me!

Comment: I'm hoping I was just doing something dumb with pyzbar. it gave me bounding boxes like these: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPlFW.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUd9H.png -- so _maybe_ the OpenCV detection part isn't necessary... but maybe it is, if (py)zbar is really that silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok since `pyzbar`/`zbar` seems to have bugs that cause its bounding boxes to catch multiple codes, or not detect codes that are rotated too much, I'll use OpenCV's barcode detection, rectify the codes, then use pyzbar for decoding. OpenCV can also decode, but not as many different types.

Approach:

- find codes, get bounding boxes
- for each bounding box, enlarge it width-wise and see what other codes it overlaps with
- build "groups"

Input:

[image: input]

Detect barcodes with OpenCV:

```py
det = cv.barcode.BarcodeDetector()
(rv, detections) = det.detect(im)
# detections: four corner points per detection
```

Extract rectangle:

```py
def extract_region_from_corners(image, corners):
    # order:
    #   [1] top left     [2] top right
    #   [0] bottom left  [3] bottom right
    (bl, tl, tr, br) = corners

    # axis vectors
    vx = tr - tl
    vy = bl - tl

    lx = np.linalg.norm(vx)
    ly = np.linalg.norm(vy)

    H = np.eye(3)
    H[0:2,2] = tl # origin
    H[:2,0] = vx / lx
    H[:2,1] = vy / ly

    dst = cv.warpAffine(src=image,
        M=H[:2], dsize=(int(lx), int(ly)),
        flags=cv.INTER_LINEAR | cv.WARP_INVERSE_MAP)

    return dst
```

Utility function:

```py
def corners_to_rrect(corners):
    # order:
    #   [1] top left     [2] top right
    #   [0] bottom left  [3] bottom right
    (bl, tl, tr, br) = corners

    vx = ((tr - tl) + (br - bl)) / 2
    vy = ((bl - tl) + (br - tr)) / 2
    lx = np.linalg.norm(vx)
    ly = np.linalg.norm(vy)

    center = tuple(corners.mean(axis=0))
    size = (lx, ly)
    angle = np.arctan2(vx[1], vx[0]) / np.pi * 180 # degrees

    return (center, size, angle)
```

Extract codes, decode, note their `RotatedRect` positions:

```py
found_codes = []
canvas = im.copy()

for detection_corners in detections:
    rrect = corners_to_rrect(detection_corners)

    (rrect_width, rrect_height) = rrect[1]
    assert rrect_width > rrect_height, ("assuming barcode lies lengthwise", rrect)

    roi = extract_region_from_corners(image=im, corners=detection_corners)

    [code] = pyzbar.decode(roi, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.CODE128, ZBarSymbol.EAN13])
    print(code.type, code.data, rrect)

    found_codes.append( (rrect, code) )

    cv.polylines(img=canvas, pts=[detection_corners.astype(np.int32)], isClosed=True, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
```

```
CODE128 b'07FFD58D47189879' ((706.9937, 355.28094), (434.7604, 65.09412), 15.141749040805594)
CODE128 b'07FFD58D47189878' ((266.48895, 361.89154), (435.78812, 65.95062), -15.051276355059604)
CODE128 b'07FFD58D47189876' ((237.65492, 816.5005), (434.7883, 65.28357), 15.058296081979087)
CODE128 b'07FFD58D47189877' ((731.69257, 817.5774), (435.56052, 62.905884), -15.084296904602034)
EAN13 b'0871828002084' ((228.3433, 239.54503), (235.90378, 66.31835), -15.219580753945182)
EAN13 b'0871828002077' ((705.7166, 693.0964), (236.39447, 65.9507), -15.102472037983436)
EAN13 b'0871828002091' ((742.64703, 237.18982), (240.23358, 67.790794), 15.171352788215723)
EAN13 b'0871828002060' ((270.11478, 696.054), (236.27463, 64.16398), 15.201185346963047)
```

[image: found_codes]

More utility functions:

```py
def enlarge_rrect(rrect, factor=1, fx=1, fy=1):
    (center, size, angle) = rrect
    (width, height) = size
    new_size = (width * factor * fx, height * factor * fy)
    return (center, new_size, angle)
```

```py
def merge_intersecting_sets(sets):
    # sets = set(map(frozenset, sets))
    while True:
        oldcount = len(sets)

        # merge or add
        newsets = set()
        for thisset in sets:
            for thatset in newsets:
                if thisset & thatset:
                    newsets.remove(thatset)
                    newsets.add(thisset | thatset)
                    break
            else:
                newsets.add(thisset)

        sets = newsets
        if len(sets) == oldcount:
            break
    
    return sets

# assert merge_intersecting_sets([{1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {5,6}]) == {frozenset({1,2,3,4}), frozenset({5,6})}
```

<sub>*Note:* This set operation has no effect on this data because the data is simple enough. Theoretically, it is required. Say you have three codes A,B,C beside each other, where A,B are adjacent and B,C are adjacent but A,C are *not* adjacent. This operation merges the sets {A,B} and {B,C} into {A,B,C}.</sub>

Determine groups using enlarged `RotatedRect` and intersection test:

```py
def associate_rrects(rrects, fx=1, fy=1):
    "associate RotatedRect instances, given enlargement factors in horizontal and vertical direction"

    # build connected components by adjacency
    components = set()
    for (i, thisrect) in enumerate(rrects):
        thisenlarged = enlarge_rrect(thisrect, fx=fx, fy=fy)

        component = {i}
        for (j, thatrect) in enumerate(rrects):
            (rv, intersection) = cv.rotatedRectangleIntersection(thisenlarged, thatrect)
            if rv != cv.INTERSECT_NONE: # i.e. INTERSECT_PARTIAL, INTERSECT_FULL
                component.add(j)

        components.add(frozenset(component))
    
    # merge intersecting components (transitivitiy)
    components = merge_intersecting_sets(components)

    return components


components = associate_rrects([rrect for rrect, code in found_codes], fy=5)
print(components)
```

```
{frozenset({1, 4}), frozenset({2, 7}), frozenset({0, 6}), frozenset({3, 5})}
```

Now you can pick from `found_codes` using those indices.

Drawing the groups, using convex hull:

```py
canvas = im.copy()
for component in components:
    component_codes = [found_codes[i] for i in component]

    component_corners = np.concatenate([
        cv.boxPoints(rrect)
        for (rrect, code) in component_codes
    ])
    hull = cv.convexHull(component_corners)
    cv.polylines(img=canvas, pts=[hull.astype(np.int32)], isClosed=True, color=(255, 255, 0), thickness=2)

    for (rrect, code) in component_codes:
        #print(rrect, code)
        cv.polylines(img=canvas, pts=[cv.boxPoints(rrect).astype(int)], isClosed=True, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=2)
        cv.putText(canvas, text=str(code.data),
            org=np.int0(rrect[0]), fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            fontScale=0.7, color=(0,0,0), thickness=8)
        cv.putText(canvas, text=str(code.data),
            org=np.int0(rrect[0]), fontFace=cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            fontScale=0.7, color=(0,255,255), thickness=2)
```

[image: canvas]

Entire thing: https://gist.github.com/crackwitz/3a7e7e5d698274198393737415ef409a

Comment: First off, thank you for taking the time to figure this out. I've tested it and confirmed it works as you said and I asked, so I have accepted the answer.
I spent time going over all your code and I understand all of it except the ```merge_intersecting_sets``` function. I cannot figure out what your intentions are with this. The values are the same coming out as going in. Could you explain that to me, please?

Comment: Also, I had no idea for/else even existed! That is pretty cool!

Comment: you can ignore/drop the set merging operation if your data is "tame" (always groups of 2 codes, with plenty of space between groups). for this demo, and your expected data, it will have no effect. it is required to be logically thorough. I've added an assertion that might clarify, or confuse. consider transitivity. put three codes A,B,C beside each other. A and B are close enough, B and C too, but A and C are *not*... so how to group them? {A,B}+{C} or {A}+{B,C}, or {A,B,C} in a single group? that's what that does.