# OpenCV barcode detection is detecting edge of sticker causing failure in barcode decode

Tags: python, opencv, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am using OpenCV to detect barcodes in the image below, but for some reason, the detection bounding box it provides is including the edge of the sticker the barcode is on, which then when I go to decode the detections, I get no results.

Am I doing wrong? How can I have OpenCV detect the barcode inside of the white sticker?

Code I am using:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('image/path/image.jpg')

det = cv2.barcode.BarcodeDetector()
(rv, detections) = det.detect(image)

for barcode in detections:
    cv2.polylines(image, [np.int32(barcode)], isClosed=True, color=(0, 0, 255), thickness=2)

cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Original Image
[image: Original Image]

Detected Image / Script Output
[image: Detected Image]

Comment: The problem is likely the lack of quiet zone to the right of each barcode.  Without the quiet zone, the search algorithm is looking for a shorter symbol that uses a wide white bar as the quite zone. Can you post process the image to add some white to the right of each label image to provide the necessary quiet zone?

Comment: @MarkWarren Ah, interesting, I did not know about the 'quiet zone' as it is called. That makes a lot of sense. I can alter future barcodes to include this, so that's good. I, however, do not know about adding a quiet zone to the existing barcodes. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm more worried that these boxes appear to NOT extend to the right end of the code... and why do you show these codes inverted? -- OpenCV _always_ gives you a longer strip than _exactly_ the code. that "overhang" may be deemed excessive. HOWEVER you can fix up those boxes yourself. here's some code to transform the corner points into a RotatedRect, for which you can easily adjust the width and height https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73565869/group-multiple-barcodes-on-a-single-sticker-together-from-an-image-with-multiple/73570634#73570634

Comment: simple fix: find the label/black box (big black area), turn the black box surroundings into white, there's some more quiet zone for you.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I don't understand how adjusting the width and height helps me extend the quiet zone. I do understand converting the black pixels around the white sticker with the barcode on it to white. But how can I do that without converting the black pixels inside the white sticker to white as well? I don't know opencv that well and so don't really know what my options are for doing something like this.

Comment: you're only detecting at this point, not decoding. how do you plan to decode, if at all? maybe you're worrying over nothing